# What is the best way to store the sql queries used during execution in Automation

Tags: java, sql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I do UI vs DB validation for every step. There are around 30 to 40 queries are being used now. Earlier we stored in Excel sheet, which gave performance issues. Later switched to creating a class .txt file for each query. Please suggest the best approach.

Comment: Do you use any kind of workbench for performing operations or queries like MySQL workbench or HeidiSQL? They do have options for saving the entire script.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't storing them in a SQL class in code? Unless they are changing regularly, which I assume they are not, there's no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to create a stored procedure for this queries. In this way if you are frequently using the same queries it will not be recompiled after first run, subsequently increasing your performance.